# LWC - Unit Testing NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl

Tags: unit-test, lightning-web-components

I've been looking to start unit testing the Lightning Web Component I've created with [LWC Jest](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc-jest) and I am running into some issues in creating my component that is making use of the [NavigationMixin](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_navigate) module. The unit test is failing to create the component when it reaches the NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl with the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

      64 |                     "title" : this.linkTitles.shift(),
      65 |                     "location" : pageRef,
    > 66 |                     "url" : this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl](pageRef).then(url => {this.links[i].url = url;}),
         |                             ^
      67 |                     "description" : this.linkDescriptions.shift()
```

I've tried wrapping the 'expect' assertion in a Promise statement as suggested [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.unit_testing_using_jest_create_tests) due to the asynchronous nature of NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl but had no luck. Tried to implement some of the jest.js [mocking examples](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions) as well but didn't have much luck.

The following is the unit test and Javascript involved.
[**Full component source**](https://github.com/Clint-Chester/sfdc-helpfullinks) is here.

**Unit Test**:

```js
// createElement is what we'll use to create our component under test
import { createElement } from 'lwc';
// helpfulLinks is the component being tested
import helpfulLinks from 'c/helpfulLinks';

describe('Helpful Links Component', () => {
    it('is chained to another component', () => {
        // Given
        const expectedClassName = 'slds-grid slds-wrap slds-color__background_gray-1 slds-box pull-up-margin';
        // When
        const element = createElement('c-helpful-links', { is: helpfulLinks });
        element.linkIcons = 'doctype:pdf;doctype:flash';
        element.linkTitles = 'Sample Title; Sample Title';
        element.linkUrlsOrIds = '/;/';
        element.linkDescriptions = 'Sample Description;Sample Description';
        element.chainLists = true;
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        const className = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('div[data-id=linksList]').className;
        // Then
        expect(className).resolves.toBe(expectedClassName);
    });
});
```

**Javascript for the Component**

```js
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class HelpfulLinks extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    //All of the settings that can be defined for the component
    @api title;
    @api navigationOptions;
    @api showTitle;
    @api chainLists;
    @api
    get linkIcons() {
        return this._linkIcons;
    }
    set linkIcons(value) {
        this._linkIcons = value.split(";");
        //Use this value to compare the lengths across all other settings
        this._linkSettingsCount = this._linkIcons.length;
    }
    @api
    get linkTitles() {
        return this._linkTitles;
    }
    set linkTitles(value) {
        this._linkTitles = value.split(";");
    }
    @api
    get linkUrlsOrIds() {
        return this._linkUrlsOrIds;
    }
    set linkUrlsOrIds(value) {
        this._linkUrlsOrIds = value.split(";");
    }
    @api
    get linkDescriptions() {
        return this._linkDescriptions;
    }
    set linkDescriptions(value) {
        this._linkDescriptions = value.split(";");
    }

    //Holds the constructed links to be rendered. Needs to be tracked for the URL display to work.
    @track
    links = [];

    //Used to return an error back to the user
    errorOccurred = false;
    errorMessage = '';

    renderedCallback() {
        //With the DOM being rendered, check whether the lists should be chained
        if(this.chainLists) {
            this.template.querySelector('div[data-id=linksList]').className = this.template.querySelector('div[data-id=linksList]').className + ' pull-up-margin';
        }
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        //Check that all the link settings are the same length
        if([this.linkIcons, this.linkTitles, this.linkUrlsOrIds, this.linkDescriptions].every(this.linkLengthSettingsMatch, this)) {
            //Set the links
            for(let i = 0; i < this._linkSettingsCount; i++) {
                let pageRef = this.constructPageRef(this.linkUrlsOrIds.shift());
                this.links.push({
                    "icon" : this.linkIcons.shift(),
                    "title" : this.linkTitles.shift(),
                    "location" : pageRef,
                    "url" : this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl](pageRef).then(url => {this.links[i].url = url;}),
                    "description" : this.linkDescriptions.shift()
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            //Set the error
            this.errorOccurred = true;
            this.errorMessage = 'Please ensure that when you fill out the icons, titles, urls and descriptions that they all have the same amount of semi colons.';
        }
    }

    navigateToTarget(event) {
        //Stop the event's default behavior.
        event.preventDefault();
        //Stop the event from bubbling up in the DOM.
        event.stopPropagation();
        //Navigate to the record page.
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](this.links[event.target.dataset.recordcount].location);
    }

    constructPageRef(urlOrId) {
        switch(this.navigationOptions) {
            case "URL":
                return {
                    type: 'standard__webPage',
                    attributes: {
                        url: urlOrId
                    }
                };
            case "Salesforce File":
                return {
                    type: 'standard__namedPage',
                    attributes: {
                        pageName: 'filePreview'
                    },
                    state : {
                        recordIds: urlOrId
                    }
                };
            case "Record Page":
                return {
                    type: 'standard__recordPage',
                    attributes: {
                        recordId: urlOrId,
                        actionName: 'view'
                    }
                };
            default:
                //As these switch values are guaranteed, this should never happen
                return null;
        }
    }

    //Utility for checking setting lengths
    linkLengthSettingsMatch(setting) {
        return setting.length === this._linkSettingsCount;
    }
}
```

Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [default mock implementation](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc-jest/blob/master/src/lightning-mocks/navigation/navigation.js) for `NavigationMixin` doesn't provide a promise.

You'll have to create your own mock implementation, either [globally for your project](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/navigation.js), or [specific to your component](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/68cd0e78fb1f2789fffc07377eb9e0f0c0aeee56/force-app/main/default/lwc/apexImperativeMethod/__tests__/apexImperativeMethod.test.js#L6), which then works for your use case. As it's not about testing `NavigationMixin` you should run the latter approach.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and it turned out to be an issue with my JEST installation. If you debug your jest unit test do you find `navigation.NavigationMixin` or `_navigation.NavigationMixin` defined? If so, you probably have the same issue. Make sure you have a `jest.config.js` file with the following:

```
const { jestConfig } = require('@salesforce/lwc-jest/config');
module.exports = {
    ...jestConfig,
    moduleNameMapper: {   
        '/^(c)\/(.+)$':'<rootDir>/force-app/main/default/lwc/$2/$2'
    },
    testPathIgnorePatterns: [
        '<rootDir>/node_modules/',
        '<rootDit>/test/specs/'
    ]
}
```

Also, in your tests import:

```
import { registerTestWireAdapter } from '@salesforce/lwc-jest';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
```

And before your describe use:

```
 registerTestWireAdapter(CurrentPageReference);
```

I'm able to use `NavigationMixin` with a promise in my test context this way, without the need to create a custom mock impolementation